# How to Implement Timer on Android quiz?

Tags: java, android, timer, imageview

I am working on Android quiz .I wanted to add timer on ImageView In `Question XML` , I want to call  the `CountDownTimer` from `Welcome XML` on Play button. I just set the `onClick` in `Question xml` by adding a line like this in ImageView

> **In Question XML**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/question"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/timer_bttn" 
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

> **In Welcome xml**

```
<Button 
            android:text="Play" 
            android:id="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_width="80dip" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dip" 
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="@drawable/start_button" />
```

> **then i created TimerActivity**

```
    public class TimerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button startB;
public TextView text;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.question);
startB = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
startB.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        text.setText(""+String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - 
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
           text.setText("done!");
        }
     }.start();

}   
}
```

In this code I have just written code of timer to call on Image and implement code in  TimerActivity. but My Timer not get started when I click a play button.Where My Play button is working in Different Activity.so can any one help me How to call Timer In different XML.

My logCat:-

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2013-09-02 17:19:38.741
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Widget has the wrong parent
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4342)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setMenu(Control.java:3462)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPanel$20.handleEvent(LogCatPanel.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.showMenu(Widget.java:1472)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmContextMenu(Widget.java:1574)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CONTEXTMENU(Control.java:4673)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.WM_CONTEXTMENU(Table.java:5972)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4532)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.windowProc(Table.java:5913)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2440)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmRButtonUp(Widget.java:2395)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_RBUTTONUP(Control.java:5134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4596)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.windowProc(Table.java:5913)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2546)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Thank's in advance

Comment: your app should crash with the code you have posted. if so post the stacktrace

Comment: post your `question.xml` you have  a imageview i don't see you initializing imageview any where. you initialize a textview with id `button1`. Make sure your views are initialized properly.

Comment: Yeah Firstly I added button there after that i remove it with ImageView Is there is some problem.or i can change it's ID too.

Comment: if you have imageview you initialize it as a iamgeview in the activity with the id mentioned in xml if you have a textview youinitialize the textview the textview. but you have `text.setText` so change imageview to textview and then initialize textview in activity. then set the text to textview

Comment: what you are doing is wrong you have textview and button is difrerent xml and you are initializing it in a single activity. your question.xml must have textview and play button.

Comment: Ok..Now I also think so But how can i call it now as it is available in different XML and Different Activity.

Comment: straight no. you can't do like that.

Comment: Ooo...so i can't able to start the timer to Click on the different XML Button to activate the Timer.

Comment: No you can't that's what i have been suggesting in my past 3- 4 comments

Comment: thnx for your precious time. This code working for Single XML and single activity. If some other way than please Gide me I have to it.

Comment: there is no other way. sorry rethink your design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your timer implementation

But you have this

```
 text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

And you have this

```
   <ImageView
android:id="@+id/button1"
```

So it should be

```
 <TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
```

And

```
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Try the below. On click of the button timer starts.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button startB;
public TextView text;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
startB = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
startB.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        text.setText(""+String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - 
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
           text.setText("done!");
        }
     }.start();

}   
}
```

Check this link

For Java versions below 1.5 or for systems that do not fully support the TimeUnit class the following equations can be used:

```
int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
int hours   = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
```

Edit:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I implemented the above code in my TimeActivity and Added a TextView in my xml  with Id Timer and Call It OnClick Play Button But I am not able start Timer as well..:(

Comment: @akashraj post your updated code it works fine no doubt about that you are doing it wrong

Comment: @akashraj check the edit it works fine. you might be doing something wrong. even posted a snap shot. check the logcat if you get exceptions.

Comment: @Raghunadan..I am still Trap in Timer Activity. It still not working on my project.My above Code is working fine When i run it individually on test Project. I am Not getting any Idea How can I proceed.

Comment: @akashraj post the updated code xml and if you get exceptions the logcat details of the crash for further assistance. If you don't post the relevant details its not possible to help further

Comment: @raghunadan i have just updated my revised code what i am trying there.and my log Cat showing this msg:-

Comment: @akashraj post your xml full.

Comment: Basically Timer text-view in this XML and PlayBtton in other XML when I clicked on Play Timer start on this XML.

Comment: timer does not start on xml. You have this java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Widget has the wrong parent. so check the xml. the code is fine

Comment: Ok.So is there is problem when i calling the Timer from different Xml .If so Then How can i call the Timer when I pressed Button in Different XML File and Call it in other XmlFile.

Comment: @akashraj you can initialize views of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. your comment is not clear. count Down timer has nothing to do with xml. But i guess you have a button and textview in a different xml than the one in `setContenvew(R.layout.question)`. You can only initialize views that is in `question.xml` since it is set for the activity

Comment: can I Implement it on Run of the Question Activity.so,timer start when My QuestionPage Loaded.

Comment: @akashraj you can do it in `onCreate` or `onResume` and stop and restart the timer ask user moves to next question. If you have new doubts pls ask a new question and stop commenting

Answer (score 0):

You should try following code.

```
private void setTimer() {
    counterTimer = new CountDownTimer(finishTime * 1000, 1000) {
        public void onFinish() {
            //code to execute when time finished
        }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;

            if (seconds < 10) {
                txtTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
            } else {
                txtTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
            }
        }
    };
    counterTimer.start();
}
```

Here `examFinishTime` is an long value like

```
private long finishTime = 5;
```

**Note:** Argument is in Miliseconds.

To start timer, just call `setTimer()` method in any button's click event.

Comment: @akashraj, do you want to add listener in another activity to get start timer? Elaborate. Your question is not much clear to me.

Comment: @chitan basically i have one ImageView(Where I have to call my Timer) In Question XMl and Play Button(In My Welcome XML).When I click on the Play Button My quiz start and i Want My Timer start too.I also created a timerActivity .

Comment: @chitan yes I wanted to add listener in another activity to to start timer.

Comment: Create one listener interface, then register it in another activity. When user click on button, fire that listener so that registered activity also get notification. :)

Comment: Can u explain me with some example i am very thankful to you. plz.

Comment: @chitan how can i do it .