# How to start Timer when Activity Loaded?

Tags: java, android, xml, timer

I am working on Timer. I have created a `TextView` in my Question XML(*Where I have to Implement Timer to display*) and `PlayButton` in Welcome XML (Timer in Question Activity Start When Play button Is Clicked) .I have `WelcomeActivity` where I have implemented `PlayButton` and `QuestionActivity` Where I wanted to Function my timer.I am attaching My Code Here:-

> **Welcome XML:-**

```
<Button 
            android:text="Play" 
            android:id="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_width="80dip" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dip" 
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="@drawable/start_button" />
```

> **Question XML:-**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/question"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/timer_bttn" 
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

> **Welcome Activity:-**

```
 public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////// GAME MENU  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
    playBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button settingsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsBtn);
    settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button rulesBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rulesBtn);
    rulesBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button exitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitBtn);
    exitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}


/**
 * Listener for game menu
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i;

    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.playBtn :
        //once logged in, load the main page
        //Log.d("LOGIN", "User has started the game");

        //Get Question set //
        List<Question> questions = getQuestionSetFromDb();

        //Initialise Game with retrieved question set ///
        GamePlay c = new GamePlay();
        c.setQuestions(questions);
        c.setNumRounds(getNumQuestions());
        ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).setCurrentGame(c);  

        //Start Game Now.. //
        i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, Constants.PLAYBUTTON);
        break;

    case R.id.rulesBtn :
        i = new Intent(this, RulesActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, Constants.RULESBUTTON);
        break;

    case R.id.settingsBtn :
        i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, Constants.SETTINGSBUTTON);
        break;

    case R.id.exitBtn :
        finish();
        break;
    }

}
```

> **QuestionActivity:-**

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    private Question currentQ;
    private GamePlay currentGame;
    protected TextView txtTimer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);
        /**
         * Configure current game and get question
         */
        currentGame = ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
        currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
        Button nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        /**
         * Update the question and answer options..
         */
        setQuestions();

    }


    /**
     * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
     * current question
     */
    private void setQuestions() {
        //set the question text from current question
        String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
        TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        qText.setText(question);

        //set the available options
        List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
        TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

        TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

        TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

        TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");
        setTimer();

        /**
         * check if end of game
         */
        if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
            //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
            Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else{
            Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }



    /**
     * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
     * has then check if its correct and update gamescore
     */
    private boolean checkAnswer() {
        String answer = getSelectedAnswer();
        if (answer==null){
            //Log.d("Questions", "No Checkbox selection made - returning");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            //Log.d("Questions", "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");
            if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
            {
                //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
                currentGame.incrementScore();
            }
            else{
                //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
                currentGame.decrementScore();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    private String getSelectedAnswer() {
        Button c1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        Button c2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        Button c3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        Button c4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        if (c1.callOnClick())
        {
            return c1.getContext().toString();
        }
        if (c2.callOnClick())
        {
            return c2.getContext().toString();
        }
        if (c3.callOnClick())
        {
            return c3.getContext().toString();
        }
        if (c4.callOnClick())
        {
            return c4.getContext().toString();
        }

        return null;
    }
    public void setTimer() {
        long finishTime = 5;
        CountDownTimer counterTimer = new CountDownTimer(finishTime * 1000, 1000) {
            public void onFinish() {
                //code to execute when time finished
            }

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                int minutes = seconds / 60;
                seconds = seconds % 60;

                if (seconds < 10) {
                    txtTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
                } else {
                    txtTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
                }
            }
        };
        counterTimer.start();
    }


}
```

I am trying To add A function in QuestionActivity But I don't know how to proceed to call my timer One activity to another Activity. so that my timer display on Question XMl after Clicking  the Play Button In Welcome XMl.Can anyone help me How to add listener in another activity Or some other way to solve My Problem.

thank's in Advance

Comment: read your question again and frankly answer: do you really understand what you wrote?

Comment: @pskink yeah I understand but i am little trap in Timer Activity.Hope this Link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567001/how-to-implement-timer-on-android-quiz) explain my question in Detail.

Comment: @akashraj: So, is this question still valid or not? Should we be answering the other question?

Comment: @JonAdams OH Yeah!! its still valid. Any answer related to my Question is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

why would you start the timer when the button is clicked?

you can set the button to go to the next activity and start the timer on that activity when

it is called...

***(sorry this is what i understand with your question: you want the timer to start when the button is clicked and the timer is on another activity?)***

Comment: Ok!! you are right but I Don't know how it start over there and Check my every question.

Comment: timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer_text);
  timerHolder = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

   
   public void onFinish() {
    isGameOver = true;
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), GameOver.class);
    startActivity(i);
   }

   
   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    timeLeft = millisUntilFinished;
    timer.setText("Time left: " + String.valueOf(timeLeft / 1000));
   }
  }.start();

here is an example.. onTick holds the timer and in onFinish the thing that you want to do when timer hits 0

Comment: first you can set the play button to go to QuestionActivity then in QuestionActivity class you can start the timer in onCreate method and thats it.

Comment: final TextView timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
CountDownTimer timerHolder = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) { 
public void onFinish() { 
currentGame.isGameOver();
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), EndgameActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
}
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
long timeLeft = millisUntilFinished; timer.setText("Time left: " + String.valueOf(timeLeft / 1000));
}
}.start(); 
} i have just implement this code inside my questionActivity at the place of setTime (); function call onClick But it cant work for me.

Comment: try putting it in oncreate make sure you have textview for timer in your xml file. and make sure you have these variables
CountDownTimer timerHolder;
long timeLeft;
TextView timer